# Question of XCode app development: How to create a dial pad for phone call?

Tags: xcode, ios4

Currently I am working on phone call app on iPhone but can't find a reusable UI for the dial pad as the one built-in on iPhone. It's dirty to layout the UI and sound for each and I would like to know does anyone have such experience?

Thanks in advance.

Charles

Answer (score 0):

I have created the dial pad, See if this would help you.

https://github.com/Kadasiddha/dailPad